# How to put .pdf file contents into varbinary(max) column

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to put the contents of a `.pdf` file into a column of type `varbinary(max)`.

How I can achieve this? I played with `convert` and `cast`, but it doesn't seem to work.

I was thinking about defining `var1 varbinary(max)` and setting it to the file's contents, but this also failed.

```
declare @var1 varbinary(max)
set @var1 'c:\xxx\inp.pdf' ???
```

and then:

```
insert into t1(xdata) values ( @var1);
```

Or maybe I can use insert from file, not sure is this possible without BULK?

Appreciate your help, I can't use contents of `.pdf` file in single qoutes either, it treats it as `varchar` -(

Thanks all for help.
Dai

Comment: Put technologies in the tags of questions, not the title.

Comment: There are ways to access a file, if that file is accessible for the account that SQL Server is running from, from the server. Is that the situation here, or is `C:\xxx\inp.pdf` a file on your local machine?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @pdf VARBINARY(MAX)

SELECT @pdf = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\......\YourFile.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Document;

SELECT @pdf, DATALENGTH(@pdf)

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(PDFContents) VALUES(@Pdf)
GO
```

or directly:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.t1(xdata) 
   SELECT BulkColumn
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\......\YourFile.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB)
```

More details on the `OPENROWSET` function can be found on [MSDN's SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) as always.

Comment: Thansk all, file is on my local c: and it worked fine.  Somehow I can't match the value from the sample file, but it's another issue, what is the good way to test this conversion?  I tried to do reverse cast(binC1 as varchar(max)) and it stopped on very first NUL value (as I see it in notepad ++) so I not able to open reversed file as pdf. This column to be viewed in www browser as pdf doc at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [blob column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895234.aspx) to which you write your document